# How to print the actual values of array from SQL queries?

Tags: java

I'm using a method *getTableContent* that fetch some values from the db and returns as String array. The methods goes as follows,

```
public static String[][] getTableContent(Connection con){

    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement st = null;        
    String [][] data = null;

    String sql = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL from COFFEES";

    try {

        st = myConn.createStatement();
        rs =  st.executeQuery(sql);

        if(rs.last()){

            data = new String[rs.getRow()][5];
            rs.beforeFirst();
        }

        int count =0;

        while ( rs != null && rs.next() ){

            data[count][0] =rs.getString(1);
            data[count][1] =rs.getString(2);
            data[count][2] =rs.getString(3);
            data[count][3] =rs.getString(4);
            data[count][4] =rs.getString(5);


        }
    } 

    catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return data;        
}
```

I get the table values in another array and trying to print as following,

```
String [][] myData =  getTableContent(conn);

    for ( int i =0; i < myData.length; i++ ){

        for (  int j =0; j < myData.length; j++ ){

            System.out.print( (myData[j]) + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

All I'm getting some machine values provided below as sample ,

```
    [Ljava.lang.String;@314e4baf [Ljava.lang.String;@4cb71983
```

I used myData[j]).toString() but that doesn't help me. How can I improve the code ? There are no error in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is mistake in your code. Yiu were directly printing 1-D array which prints hashcode and not actual array content. I have rectified it below:

```
 for ( int i =0; i < myData.length; i++ ){

        for (  int j =0; j < myData[i].length; j++ ){
           // you were printing the 1-D array, which prints hashcode
            System.out.print( (myData[i][j]) + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Alternatively try this:

```
 String [][] myData =  getTableContent(conn);

 for (int i =0; i < myData.length; i++){
   System.out.println( Arrays.toString(myData[i]));
 }
```

Comment: Now I can see that and I changed the code. I also forget to add count++ in the end of getTableContent method. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It indeed resolved the issue, I'm just not allowed by the system to accept an answer within 3 minutes ;-)